# How do I export a website made in Dotcms?

Tags: wget, dotcms, httrack

I'm trying to save one of my websites (with all its files) to my pc so i can upload it to another server. I've tried using Httrack and wget but with both I only got a small part of the images and most of it was scattered in a new folder called contentAsset. could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

dotCMS can publish your site statically - set up a static Push Publishing endpoint and then right click and publish your site to it.  dotCMS will write out your site and assets statically to a folder under the /assets directory.